# JMeter ForEach Controller transaction name with multiple iteration

Tags: jmeter

Im using JMeter foreach controller and depending on the list of values the transactions names are updated. 
Problem is transaction names are starting from the point where iteration:1 is ended.
But i want the value to ** restart ** every iteration.
screen1:
[image]
Screen2:
[image]
Screen3:
[image]
Screen4:
[image]

Comment: You can upvote answer if it was helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove your Beanshell Sampler and get current iteration number as

```
${__jm__ForEach Controller__idx}
```

[image: JMeter ForEach Controller Index]

More information:

- [Bug 61802 - Loop / ForEach Controller should expose a variable for current iteration](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61802)
- [What’s New in JMeter 4.0?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-4)

---

Also be aware that according to JMeter Best Practices you should:

- [Always use the latest version of JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version)
- [Switch to JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of User Defined Variables, set val variable in [User Parameters](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Parameters) and check `Update Once Per Iteration`:

> Update Once Per Iteration A flag to indicate whether the User Parameters element should update its variables only once per iteration

This way it'll update val with 0 every iteration and not only once.